# Receiving emails in my iCloud account that are addressed to another user name that is not mine

Tags: icloud, email

Over the last year, I have been receiving emails from a username that is my wife's name but has no association with my iCloud email account.  I went into my iCould account to see if we had accidentally set up an account and associated it with our icloud account but there is no such account.  Also, when I try to log in to icloud using this supposed email it says it does not exist.  Furthermore, the icloud email in question arrives in my existing/regularly used inbox.  Somehow, it appears it is spam.  Somehow, it ends up in my inbox but under a different username.  I am baffled.  The emails that come are confirming subscriptions to Monat or to Dolly Parton Stampede.  It looks like possible "phishing" or something.  Any ideas on how to stop receiving these emails?  Thank you!

Comment: I did a test and sent an email to the email in question using a gmail account.  The email did arrive in my personal icloud inbox.  This means that this username/email that includes my wife's name is somehow associated with my icloud email.  However, when I look at my icloud account/apple ID, I do not see any email that is even close to this email.  Possibly, years ago, I created this username however, it is no where to be found now.  Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you change the password of that iCloud account?  If so, you should do it now.  I would then recommend that you change your iCloud account or contact Apple Support to see if they can help.